# GWT compiler failing with status 139

Tags: gwt, errai

I am building my [app](https://github.com/moravianlibrary/MEditor/tree/master/editor-webapp) with *gwt-maven-plugin* (command `mvn clean install -Denv=cuni -rf :editor-webapp`).
But all what I got is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile (gwt-goals) on project editor-webapp: Command [[

...

[ERROR] ]] failed with status 139
```

without any further information. When running the maven with `-X -e` options no root cause is printed.

**So here is my question:**
Where can I find all those magic status codes of GWT compiler with some description what they actually mean?

EDIT: I've just found out that 139 stands for Segmentation fault (lucky me :))

NOTE:
I was able to compile the app before merging the git branch containing the Errai changes into the master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by `-Xmx4086m` option. The `-Xmx1536m` works well. Still, if anyone could provide a link to the table with the GWT compiler status codes, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Where did you find out that 139 stands for Seg Fault?  I'd also be interested in such a table if you come across one.

Comment: I run the command directly without the maven i.e. `java -Xmx4086m -classpath all_the_jars:gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -gen /home/jkremser/install/eclipse-meditor/workspace/MEditor/editor-webapp/target/.generated -logLevel INFO -style DETAILED -war /home/jkremser/install/eclipse-meditor/workspace/MEditor/editor-webapp/target/editor-webapp-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 1 -draftCompile -strict cz.mzk.editor.MEditorDev cz.mzk.editor.RequestForAddingDev` And it wrote Segmentation Fault to terminal. And `echo $?` returned 139